# Acousto-optic modulator in pst-optexp?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

`pst-optexp` not only creates beautiful graphics but also it provides a way to logically describe complex optical setups.

one thing I found missing is the ability to define an acousto optical modulator.
basically this could be described by something like `\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate]` but with the appearance of a box instead of a line, or something similar.
does anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example image of how it should look like? Maybe using `\mirror[mirrortype=semitrans]` or `\transmissiongrating[gratingcount=0, gratingalign=center]` could provide a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Version 4.8 now has an `\optaom` component. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,2)
  \pnodes(0,1.5){A}(3,0.5){B}(3,1.5){C}
  \optaom[aomalign=symmetric](A)(B)(C){AOM}
  \newpsstyle{Beam}{linewidth=5\pslinewidth, arrows=->}
  \drawbeam[linecolor=red!50](A){}(C)
  \drawbeam[linecolor=red](A){}(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The old answer as reference:

Here are two use cases for an AOM, which work with `\optbox`. To draw the refracted beam, you must interrupt the `\drawbeam` at the AOM and restart.

If you want the code to reflect the logic structure, you just define your own `\aom` with `\newpsobject{aom}{optbox}{}`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0.7,-0.5)(8.5,3)
  \pnode(2,1){A}\pnode(7,1){B}\pnode([offset=2]B){C}
  \pnode(8,0){D}\pnode(D|C){E}
  \psset[optexp]{mirrortype=extended, optboxsize=1.2 0.7}
  \newpsobject{aom}{optbox}{}
  \optbox[position=start, innerlabel](A)(B){Laser}
  \aom[innerlabel, position=0.2](A)(B){AOM}
  \mirror(A)(B)(C)
  \mirror(\oenodeOut{2})(D)(E)
  \addtopsstyle{Beam}{arrows=->, arrowscale=1.5, linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
  \drawbeam[beaminside=false]{1-3}(C)
  \drawbeam{2}{4}(E)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,3.5)
  \pnode(1,3.5){A}\pnode(1,1.5){B}\pnode(2,0.5){C}
  \newpsobject{aom}{optbox}{}
  \aom[label=0 0 . absolute, optboxsize=0.7 1.2](A)(B){AOM}
  \optretplate[label=1 180](\oenodeOut{1})(C){$\lambda/4$}
  \mirror[mirrortype=extended](\oenodeOut{1})(C)(\oenodeOut{1})
  \addtopsstyle{Beam}{ArrowInside=->, arrowscale=1.5, arrowinset=0, linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
  \drawbeam(A){1}\drawbeam{1-2}\drawbeam{3-2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or do you have some special needs for the AOM regarding the automatic rotation, alignment, componente nodes, fiber AOM?

Comment: First- thanks you for this super quick reply. I wasn't aware this forum is so alert..

Comment: First- thanks you for this super quick reply. I wasn't aware this forum is so alert.. The example above does the trick, but it would be great if an aom could be implemented with some parameters specific to it, for example: diffraction angle, maybe calculated from wavelength and rf drive frequency? or is this too much? I'm pretty new to all this tex graphics world (the things discover whiting a thesis!). Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking about how to implement an AOM properly. It is all about the proper alignment and rotation, and the separation of the output nodes. You won't be able to specify the diffraction angle as function of e.g. RF frq—that is not how `pst-optexp` works. The diffraction angle will be determined by some nodes which are given to the component. Do you have a specific behaviour in mind (and an example picture from a paper / hand drawing)?

Comment: It should look something like this [RP](http://www.rp-photonics.com/img/aom.png). The exact alignment and physics are not that important for the purpose of drawing it nicely. It should be possible to define how many diffracted orders are visible and the 0th order should be accessible, unlike the implementation of \transmissiongrating. Also an RF input would be nice and will enalbe drawing complex electro-optical setups. BTW-Using \beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate,bssize=0] and adding an \optbox on top looks ok. But it would be nice to be able to do it in one line instead of adding two components.